# How to put null values from Excel to DB2 database

Tags: java, db2

Can anyone suggest me how can I write Java code to import null values which is present in my `Excel to DB2 database`. I am using ibatis framework.
My Excel contains data and also null values but I can able to put data values but I cannot able put the null values it is giving me `batch update exception`.

Comment: In Java, you can use `null` literal to examine whether value is missing or not. Please include small and concise code that you're working on.

Comment: The biggest thing you're going to have to do is make sure your tables are defined to allow nulls.

Comment: yea it allows null values. But still it is giving me exception.